# How can you force Twitter's Scala Eval to prevent injecting code? I would like to limit Eval to specifying config parameters

Tags: scala, twitter, eval

I love the idea of "code as data" for configuration, because the validation you get from case classes is the same validation that you want for a configuration file.  Twitter wrote a nice Eval utility that makes this easy (https://github.com/twitter/util).  I would like to allow users to upload configuration files to a remote service.  That opens up the potential to inject code against my remote service.

For example, if I have the following config case class:

```
case class MyConfig(param1: String)
```

I would like the user to be able to upload a file containing the command:

```
MyConfig(param1 = "My Param Value")
```

...but not a file containing the command:

```
MyConfig(param1 = {import someDangerousPackage; someDangerousCommand(); "My Param Value"})
```

Is there a way to intercept the compilation to make sure no functions are being called?

Comment: If you already have the case classes, why don't you just use typesafe config for the config file and extract it from there?

Comment: take a look at http://code.google.com/p/scalascriptengine/ I think they provide some basic security options

Comment: If I create and validate a case class instance using a Typesafe Config HOCON file, then my line numbers would reflect the generated case class, not the original HOCON -- unless I'm misunderstanding the approach...

Comment: I changed my injection example  to include an import, since I can probably (hopefully) solve this problem by preventing the class loader from importing packages...maybe...

Answer (score 0):

People can add dangerous code without importing packages; how many lines of code does it take to issue a rm ... command?

The best solution is not to let people send code for configuration; just use an XML parser or such like. The only really safe alternative would be to parse the upload yourself and compare it to a strict whitelist of keywords (and quoted strings) they're allowed to use. By this point you're half way to writing your own interpreter and still vulnerable to a lot of mistakes, so parsing text files starts to seem like the lazy option as well as the safe one.

Comment: Thanks, Josiah.  I ended up abandoning Twitter Eval and going with a custom DSL using Scala Parser Combinators.  It's actually easier than parsing XML once you get past the syntax.

Comment: @ToddFlanders please close question